# Set custom classes with angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I need to create classes with a background color returned by the bank, how can I do this with Angular? I know there is a way to do this, perhaps using @ViewChildren.

These are classes that I will create with the return of the database, where I will have people name and a background color for it, I need to set this css when rendered my component.

```
.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-month-view .e-work-days.eduard,
.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-vertical-view .e-work-hours.eduard {
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.26);
}

.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-month-view .e-work-days.alice,
.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-vertical-view .e-work-hours.alice {
    background-color: #deecfc;
}

.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-month-view .e-work-days.roger,
.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-vertical-view .e-work-hours.roger {
    background-color: rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.39);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Renderer2` to create a `style` tag element and in that you can insert your custom css from your `component`, and finally you can inject that tag in your document body:

```
constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {
let myCss = `.schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-month-view .e-work-days.eduard,
                      .schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-vertical-view .e-work-hours.eduard {
                            background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.26);
                      }

                  .schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-month-view .e-work-days.alice,
                   .schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-vertical-view .e-work-hours.alice {
                          background-color: #deecfc;
                    }

                    .schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-month-view .e-work-days.roger,
                    .schedule-group-custom-work-days.e-schedule .e-vertical-view .e-work-hours.roger {
                        background-color: rgba(210, 105, 30, 0.39);
                    }`;

let styles = document.createElement('style');

styles.type = 'text/css';
styles.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myCss));
this.renderer2.appendChild(document.body, styles);

}
```

Comment: Right, would that be the best practice to apply css dynamically? Do I have to use Renderer2 to remove the class? Or is it not necessary to remove when I do not want to display the element on the screen?

Comment: well i am not sure if its the most efficient way to achieve this, but it does the job and if you want to remove classes you can update using Renderer2, also it will not affect your styling if it stays like it, but its always better to get rid of unused css.